# Need to display entry and exit time of when a case enters a queue

Tags: sql, databricks

I have caseid , history postion (which orders the sequence of events ) and then eventdte time for those events , and then entery and exit column which tells when the case entered and exited the queue. the last 2 columns need to display the time of entry and exit on the row where the case exites .. there could be multiple entry and exit but I only wnat to display when there is an entry and an exit following that. if there is a second exit and no second entry ignore that.

(case when left_goodleap_queue is true then event_datetime end) as time_left_goodleap_queue ,
case
when left_goodleap_queue is true
then first_value(case when entered_goodleap_queue is true then event_datetime end) IGNORE NULLS over (partition by loan_id, case_id order by history_position desc ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) end as time_entered_goodleap_queue   ,

this is what I have works for second scenario in screen shot not the first

display the entry and exit time on the row where the case exited